# Genarating a word document based on a form filled data

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a document (Microsoft Word 2010) that needs to to be printed (a contract). Each time, some part are different:

- name
- date
- product name
- phone number

I need a way such when I open the document a form pops up and asks me these info. When I submit the form, my word document is generated with these new data. Unfilled data will be left for hand writing.

I am not asking here about a fill-able form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ASK fields](http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/word-help/field-codes-ask-field-HP010077962.aspx) to prompt the user to enter information.